# How to install on a laptop w/o internet access?

Tags: installation

I am trying to get software for a laptop we got for free but needs software on it.  This laptop has no internet acess yet because of this.  I have downloaded the file to my current desktop but how do I make a bootable USB if I do not have Ubuntu on my pc?  Do I need to make bootable DVD for this application?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have Ubuntu on your PC. Download [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), and make a bootable media from the downloaded ISO file. After that you can install it to the laptop.

Note: `unetbootin` is just one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rufus also if you don't need persistence and only have a Windows machine to create the LiveUSB/CD/DVD.